# Career stack forgot where I was before

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I was trying to apply for a job without login , then a popup screen came asking to login or proceed with login, I preferred to login but my last search job vanished .

Comment: Try checking your browser history to recover the webpage you were at?

Comment: actually stack must be taking me to the previous page once i login

Comment: I was able to repro, agreed it's annoying. I'll see if we can get a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report, Arun. This is fixed now.

<sub><sup>Slaying the dragons of [`HandleSuccess`](https://twitter.com/JasonPunyon/status/401022256194662400) is not for the weak.</sup></sub>

Comment: So who was the last to touch it? ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Me. I just fixed it :P